# Comparing list and int in python

Tags: python, list, integer, compare

I'm trying to run the following piece of code:

```
TN = np.sum((1 - predict) * (1 - actual))
```

where I have **predicted**, the variable that I cannot modify, which gets printed as follow:

```
[False False False False False False]
```

without any comma, so I guess it is not a list.
Then, I have **actual** which is formatted as:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

They have the same length, but when I run the command above I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

How can I convert the variable **actual** so it can be compared to **predicted**?

Comment: How `predicted` is generated? can you know its type using `type()`?

Comment: This is a numpy operation and `predicted` seems to be a numpy array so if you convert `actual` to a numpy array you can do the operation: `TN = np.sum((1 - predict) * (1 - np.array(actual)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[False False False False False False]` is a numpy array:

```
l = [False, False, False, False, False, False]

a = np.array(l)
print(a)

# Output
[False False False False False False]
```

I think you have to convert `actual` to numpy array.